# Initiating a git repository slows all command-line commands, causes git commands to hang

Tags: git, bash, macos, terminal

I have a code base that I expanded from a zip file and worked on for some hours. After running `git init` from the command line in that repository, all commands from that directory slow down to a crawl. More specifically, they work as intended, but then hang afterwards for upwards of 10 seconds before I get my prompt back. Removing the `.git` directory from the project fixes everything, but re-running `git init` causes my commands to slow to a crawl again. Commands run from other directories are not affected. What is happening here?

Also, besides all my commands like `ls` and `cd` taking forever, `git add -A` hangs indefinitely after printing

> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/node_modules/memory-fs/README.md.

for every file. (I understand the warning, I've just never seen it before and I'm not sure it's related).

I'm on a 2011 MacBook Pro running El Capitan, 10.11.4.

Comment: It sounds like you have your shell set up to check whether you are in a Git repository, and if so, run various auxiliary commands. One or more of those commands are very slow (e.g., are reaching out on the network to find something, for some reason). Check your bash variables such as `$PS1`.

Comment: you're correct, i have a git prompt theme. haven't had any trouble with it before though. but following your advice i'm now seeing that the git prompt shows 34,000+ files in need of staging. i'm guessing this is why people put `node_modules` in `.gitignore`. thanks!